# i want make a script active or inactive every 3 tries

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want something like this

```cs
static int loadCount = 0;
    
void Start()
{
    if (loadCount == 3)
    {
        loadCount = 0;
        AdManager.setActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        loadCount++;
        AdManager.setActive(false);
    }
    
}
```

Ad  Manager is the name of another script I have

Comment: Can you format your code, please? Can you also state the problem with your code?

Comment: you can change the state of boolean with `!` : `active = !active;` and if you want to change it every 3rd iteration - you can use `loadCount % 3 == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as expected, but the problem is that your gameObject gets deleted when you unload the scene. When the gameObject gets deleted, all its data is deleted (so loadCount will reset to 0 every time you load the scene). Therefore, you have to make the gameObject to be not destroyed when unloaded. Here should be the code you need:

```cs
int loadCount = 0;

void Start()
{
    gameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad();

    if (loadCount == 3)
    {
        loadCount = 0;
        AdManager.setActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        loadCount++;
        AdManager.setActive(false);
    }
}
```